# HTML unordered list with column-count > 1

Tags: html, css

I have a bit of HTML with an unordered list inside a div with column-count = 2 and column-gap = 1em, like this:

CSS:

```css
.bestiary-sheet #nb-spells {
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 1em;
}
```

HTML:

```html
     <div id="nb-spells">
      <ul>
        <li>Aura-12</li>
        <li>Detect Magic-12</li>
        <li>Light-12</li>
        <!-- other entries omitted -->
      </ul>
    </div>
```

When displayed, the second column starts a few pixels higher than the rest, as shown in this image:

[image]

How can I make sure the second column starts level with the first?

Comment: Do you have padding in the .bestiary-sheet class?

Comment: Please provide code that replicates the problem, because at the moment is [doesn't](https://jsfiddle.net/k4xvyac6/),. Better still provide a [mcve]

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the list into columns, not the parent.

```css
#nb-spells ul {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="nb-spells">
  <ul>
    <li>Aura-12</li>
    <li>Detect Magic-12</li>
    <li>Light-12</li>
    <!-- other entries omitted -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@beergeek
Just set **margin-top** to be **zero** for the **UL** it will fix the problem you have, like this:

```css
        .bestiary-sheet #nb-spells {
            column-count: 2;
            column-gap: 1em;
        }

        .bestiary-sheet #nb-spells ul {
            margin-top: 0px !important;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="bestiary-sheet">
    <div id="nb-spells">
        <ul>
            <li>Aura-12</li>
            <li>Detect Magic-12</li>
            <li>Light-12</li>
            <li>Light-1332</li>
            <li>Aura-12</li>
            <li>Detect Magic-12</li>
            <li>Light-12</li>
            <li>Light-1332</li>
            <li>Aura-12</li>
            <li>Detect Magic-12</li>
            <li>Light-12</li>
            <li>Light-1332</li>
            <li>Aura-12</li>
            <li>Detect Magic-12</li>
            <li>Light-12</li>
            <li>Light-1332</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

[image: My Result]

Comment: Do not recommend using `!important` . It should only be used as an absolute last resort and with **extreme** caution.

Comment: @JonP since I don't know what **previous styling rules have been set to that UL**, I have used that, to **ensure that margin is removed**.

Comment: Style clashes should be dealt with properly, using more specific selectors, not the `!important` sledgehammer.  Work with what we have been given not with hypothetical imaginary code. You are potentially encoraging a new programmer to use `!important` which is [a bad practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: I am not encouraging a new programmer as you referring to web developer, I just wanted to tell him where he need to change, and showing him the result, from his end, he need to do some research and stuff like that, the main point for me is to TELL and SHOW where to look at. Can you try to understand this please if it is not hard

Comment: Plus can you tell me where things go wrong when I am telling what exactly should be removed its margin? Can you post a mistake comes from my important which I have used for one single UL ? Can you post that with some UL, try add 5 UL and post the answer please

Comment: Relax, removing margin is a perfectly valid solution. Using `!important` is not. It is needed with the code as provided. I am simply pointing out using `!important` is a bad practice and should only be used as a last resort, not a first preference. "Can you try to understand this please if it is not hard"

Comment: @JonP thank for explaining that but as I said we don’t know what style he is using and where is overwritten. But we can tell from using ID for that DIV, it MUST only ONE and then it is safely you can do it, if that was a Class that solution was not good because you are widely used and they all be overwritten.  Thank you again hope you are not feeling bad about that, plus we both in one side.